# Populating jstree with JSON

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, jstree

I am trying to populate a jstree. I have been working on this all night and still achieved nothing. I have a script called `display.php` on my server. It produces this response text:

```
[{
    "data": "Factory 1: (1-1000)",
    "state": "closed",
    "children": [{
        "data": 649
    }, {
        "data": 108
    }, {
        "data": 86
    }, {
        "data": 46
    }]
}, {
    "data": "Factory 2: (1001-2000)",
    "state": "closed",
    "children": {
        "data": "No child nodes"
    }
}, {
    "data": "Factory 3: (2001-3000)",
    "state": "closed",
    "children": [{
        "data": 2435
    }, {
        "data": 2951
    }, {
        "data": 2313
    }]
}, {
    "data": "Factory 4: (3001-4000)",
    "state": "closed",
    "children": [{
        "data": 3952
    }, {
        "data": 3722
    }, {
        "data": 3593
    }, {
        "data": 3252
    }, {
        "data": 3893
    }, {
        "data": 3854
    }, {
        "data": 3320
    }, {
        "data": 3092
    }]
}, {
    "data": "Factory 5: (4001-5000)",
    "state": "closed",
    "children": {
        "data": "No child nodes"
    }
}]
```

Based all the documentation (which is quite terrible) that I could find, this should be a valid object ready to be passed to the jstree object. Please tell me how to populate my tree with this JSON object.

**EDIT**

Here's how I'm trying to call the jstree:

```
$("#treeview").jstree({
    "json_data" : {
        "ajax" : {
        "url" : "libs/display.php"
        }
    }
    "plugins" : ["themes", "html_data", "ui", "crrm", "contextmenu", "json_data"], contextmenu: {items: customMenu, select_node: true}
});
```

Comment: Show how you're using the jsTree.

Comment: I would first try to rule out a PHP issue by using a static JSON file - and even better, rule out Ajax by supplying the data directly from within the .js file.

Comment: How should my function to call jstree look to do that? I have searched the documentation, but it only contains very vague examples, none of which help me with my particular needs at the moment.

Comment: What version of jsTree are you using? Is the php script setting the correct json content header? (application/json; charset=utf-8)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var loDatas = [];
$("#maintree").jstree({
    "core": {
        "themes": {
            "responsive": false
        },
        "check_callback": true,
        'data': loDatas
    },
    "types": {
        "default": {
            "icon": "fa fa-folder icon-state-warning icon-lg"
        },
        "file": {
            "icon": "fa fa-file icon-state-warning icon-lg"
        }
    },
    "state": { "key": "demo2" },
    "plugins": ["state", "types", "unique", "json_data", "search"]
});

var  lsTreeData = [{
                        "text": "Factory 1: (1-1000)",
                        "state": "closed",
                        "children": [{
                            "text": 649
                        }, {
                            "text": 108
                        }, {
                            "text": 86
                        }, {
                            "text": 46
                        }]
                    }, {
                        "text": "Factory 2: (1001-2000)",
                        "state": "closed",
                        "children": {
                            "text": "No child nodes"
                        }
                    }, {
                        "text": "Factory 3: (2001-3000)",
                        "state": "closed",
                        "children": [{
                            "text": 2435
                        }, {
                            "text": 2951
                        }, {
                            "text": 2313
                        }]
                    }, {
                        "text": "Factory 4: (3001-4000)",
                        "state": "closed",
                        "children": [{
                            "text": 3952
                        }, {
                            "text": 3722
                        }, {
                            "text": 3593
                        }, {
                            "text": 3252
                        }, {
                            "text": 3893
                        }, {
                            "text": 3854
                        }, {
                            "text": 3320
                        }, {
                            "text": 3092
                        }]
                    }, {
                        "text": "Factory 5: (4001-5000)",
                        "state": "closed",
                        "children": {
                            "text": "No child nodes"
                        }
                    }];

                    $('#maintree').jstree(true).settings.core.data = lsTreeData;
                    $('#maintree').jstree(true).refresh();
                    $("#maintree").jstree("open_all");
                    $("#maintree").jstree("deselect_all");
```

Comment: change the json data field into text field. it will working fine.